# A powershell loop to paste data from one excel sheet to another

Tags: excel, powershell, loops, foreach

I am trying to write a loop to copy data from the same row but different columns in a "summary" sheet within the same workbook. No error occurs, but no copy and paste occur. What is the issue with this code?

```
$col = (11)
foreach($col in $columns){
   $worksheet.Cells.Item(9, $col).copy()
   $summary.range("B2).PasteSpecial($xlPasteValues,$xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,$false,
   $true)
   $summary.activate() }
```

Comment: Take a look at that part $summary.range("B2)...

Comment: Manipulating Excel via the com objects is painful! Fortunatel the [ImportExcel module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.8.0) is much easier to use and this article by [Adam Bertrand](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-excel/#using-powershell-to-import-to-excel) has most, if not all, of the info to do it.

Comment: I fixed the quotation at end of B2 - but it is still not doing anything